# Hadoop - Defining and working on data with no delimeter , nospace/space between some columns

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase

I am new to hadoop and trying to import a file in hive. The source data I am using has no delimeter in between some of the columns.

Example:

```
0000856214AB25    256 T PL1423AS ......
2563458547CD12   748 S  AK2523YU ... and so on...
```

I have imported this file from mainframe in txt format.  I have fields with a fixed number of characters 1st column(1-10) , 2nd column(11-12), 3rd column(13-14))

The result I want is to read this raw data as follows:

```
   1st column - 0000856214
   2nd column - AB
   3rd column - 25 
   4th column - 256
   5th column - T
   6th column - PL
   7th column - 1423AS
```

How can I import this data with hive?

Comment: You could try using RegEx SerDe, which allows you to parse your columns according to regular expression, for example  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-ApacheWeblogData

Comment: I am new to it. can you please help me with an example.? that would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: @Palash updated the solution, please check with your input.

Comment: can some1 help me for the same?? my last queryyyyyyy.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this?.

**input.txt**

```
0000856214AB25    256 T PL1423AS
2563458547CD12   748 S  AK2523YU
```

**Hive table creation with regex:**

```
hive> CREATE TABLE test_regex(
    >f1 STRING,f2 STRING,
    >f3 STRING,f4 STRING,
    >f5 STRING,f6 STRING,
    >f7 STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
    >WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = 
    >"([0-9]{10})([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{2})\\s+([0-9]{3})\\s+([A-Z]{1})\\s+([A-Z]{2})([A-Z0-9]{6})",
    >"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5s %6s %7s")
    >STORED AS TEXTFILE;
OK
Time taken: 0.056 seconds
```

**Data Loading:**

```
hive> load data local inpath 'input.txt' overwrite into table test_regex;
OK
Time taken: 0.183 seconds
```

**Column selection:**

```
hive> select f1,f3,f5,f7 from test_regex;
OK
0000856214  25  T   1423AS
2563458547  12  S   2523YU

hive> select *from test_regex;
OK
0000856214  AB  25  256 T   PL  1423AS
2563458547  CD  12  748 S   AK  2523YU
Time taken: 0.094 seconds
```

Comment: followed each steps. its showing NULL records. Please help 
pfb

hive> select *from test_regex;
OK
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

(3 same rows in betweem)

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.186 seconds, Fetched: 11 row(s)

Comment: Its working fine for the input that you mentioned. Can you paste all your input records?

Comment: m able to run select *from test_regex;
bt getting error in select f1,f3,f5 from test_regex;

Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator

Ended Job = job_201410831439_0239 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://masterhost.localdomain:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201410131439_0239
Examining task ID: task_201410181439_0239_m_000002 (and more) from job job_201410181439_0239

Task with the most failures(4):
-----
Task ID:
  task_201410181439_0239_m_000000

please help.thnx

Comment: Hi Siva,

Can you please help me for the above error.

when i am trying to run "select card_no from employee" in employee table it is working fine.

 here "select * from test_regex" is working fine but "select f1 from test_regex" is throeing above error.

Please help to solve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check its working in local mode or not?.  Run this command  <set hive.exec.mode.local.auto=true;> and then run the query.

Comment: hive> select f1 from test_regex;

Automatically selecting local only mode for query
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Execution log at: /tmp/pr5007836/pr5007836_20141201184444_1177aaf2-9df2-46b0-a418-d2992211b730.log
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /data/1/mapred/local/localRunner/pr5007836/job_local824798484_
0001/tmp does not exist

.
.
.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask


getting this error again. can you help!! thanks

Comment: Hi,
If i want to count spaces also from my input. what changes should i make to the query.

Example:

000ABC T 9021
52 DEA R  231

HERE 1st input is fine i can do using the same query.
But in 2nd
52 DEA R  231

i want to get output as "52 " , "DEA" , "R" , " 231"
which will include space as well in couting the string.

Please let me know if need some more clarification of the query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sivasakthi Jayaraman for the solution

I found a solution for my last error.

1. download jar `hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar`
   (in my case I was having `hive-contrib-0.12.0-cdh5.0.2.jar` in `/usr/lib/hive/lib/` path. )
2. `ADD JAR /home/user17/hive/hive-contrib-0.8.1.jar`
   (in my case - `ADD JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-0.12.0-cdh5.0.2.jar` )
3. you will see it will be added.

Now,

```
select f1 from test_regex;
```

0000856214

2563458547

(as expected)